# Partially convert column in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a column in a Python dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Product_ID
ABCD
1234
0001234
2345
4567
EFGH
```

It is currently stored as an object datatype. However, I do want the numbers to be consolidated (i.e. 1234 is the same product as 0001234). Since there are also text strings in the column, I can't convert it to integer

```
df['Product_ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Product_ID'])
```

ValueError: Unable to parse string "ABCD" at position 0.

Can I use a function to convert those entries to integers (or at least strip the leading 0s) that don't contain text characters?

Ultimately, I want to group by this column and don't want separate entries for 1234 and 0001234.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not retain your column as a string? If you want "1234" and "0001234" to be treated the same, you can always strip off the leading zeros.

```
df.Product_ID.astype(str).str.lstrip('0')

0    ABCD
1    1234
2    1234
3    2345
4    4567
5    EFGH
Name: Product_ID, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a lstrip to remove the unwanted zeros.

```
df['ABCD'] = df['ABCD'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('0'))
```

You will be able to perform groub by afterwards without converting the column's type.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.drop_duplicates` to @coldspeed's answer like this to remove duplicate occurrences:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['ABCD'], ['1234'], ['0001234'], ['2345'], ['4567'], ['EFGH']], columns=['Product_ID'])
df.Product_ID = df.Product_ID.map(lambda x:x.lstrip('0'))
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Product_ID'], keep = 'first')

    Product_ID
0   ABCD
1   1234
3   2345
4   4567
5   EFGH
```